# append is randomly causing errors

Tags: python, list, append, nonetype

I am trying to append the new user inputs and for some reason it will give me a NoneType error when I try to use addAccount more than once but then will randomly work more than once.

```
def accountDisplay(bankAccount):
    print("\nID\tName\tBalance\tIntrest")
    
    for bank in bankAccount:
        for item in bank:
            print(item, end="\t")
        print()

def addAccount(bankAccount,user):
    name=input("Enter your name? ")
    balance=int(input("what is your balance? "))
    time=int(input("how many years would you like to invest?"))
    futureBalance=(balance*(1+(time*0.025)))
    bank=[user,name,balance,futureBalance]
  

    bankAccount.append(bank)
    print(name," has been added.")
      
def removeAccount(bankAccount):
    
    remove=int(input("please type the ID number to remove your account"))
    
    remove = remove-1
    bankAccount.pop(remove)
        
def moveAccount(bankAccount):
    selectAccount=int(input("please select the account to move"))
    x=bankAccount.index(selectAccount)
    print(x)
    newMove=int(input("where would you like to move the account?"))
    bankAccount.insert(newMove,move)
   
    print(bankAccount, "has been moved")
    
def editAccount(bankAccount):
    
    editID=int(input("please type the ID number to edit your account"))
    optionID=int(input("\n1:edit balance\n2:edit name."))
    if(optionID==1):
        balance=input("type the new balance")
        bank.append(balance)
    elif(optionID==2):
        name=input("type the new name")
        bank.append(name)
    bankAccount.append(bank)
        
def main():
    toContinue=1
    
    user=3
    john=[1,"john doe", 6543, 34567]
    jane=[2, "jane doe", 345, 765]
   
    bankAccount=[]
    bankAccount.append(john)
    bankAccount.append(jane)
    
    print("====================================================" ,"\n","Welcome to ABC banking","\n","this program will ask you for you name,account balance and will", "\n","allow you too withdraw and deposit from your account aswell as","\n","calculate the intrest for you. your accounnt information will be displayed afterward.","\n","==========================================================")

    while toContinue==1:
        
        display=int(input("1:display accounts\n2:add an account\n3:remove account\n4:edit account\n9:exit\n"))
    
        if (display==1):
            bankAccount=accountDisplay(bankAccount)

        elif (display==2):
            addAccount(bankAccount,user)
            user+=1
            
        elif (display==3):
            bankAccount=removeAccount(bankAccount)
        elif (display==4):
            bankAccount=moveAccount(bankAccount)
        else:
            print("error, invalid input try again.")
        toContinue=int(input("want to continue? press 1 to continue any other key to quit: "))

    print("thank you for using Samuel Banking.")

main()
```

I tried adding `return` statements for `bankAccount` and `bank` so it would return the correct values in the loop but this did not help, I just wan this to add a new user when ever it is used.

Comment: `accountDisplay()` doesn't return anything, so `bankAccount=accountDisplay(bankAccount)` sets `backAccount` to `None`. Why did you think you needed to assign the variable there?

Comment: None of the functions return `bankAccount` -- get rid of all those `bankAccount =` when you call the functions.

Comment: Removing the =bankAccount returns fixed it thanks